# A responsive web page unexpected stretches its element at a certain screen width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Can you please take a look at this web page: http://tagrig.herokuapp.com/
I am not sure why the content in the section tag will magnetically attach to the right side of screen when I resize the screen width from 1424px to 1423px. I found the issue happens in both Chrome and Firefox.

I expect the section can always keep in the middle and leave the margin until the width is reduced to less than 480px.

Would you please tell me how to fix this issue. Thank you.

Comment: You really need to add more info to this question (like the fact that the issue seems to be IE specific), and a jsfiddle would be infinitely better than some link to some external website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main wrapper is exceeding the 100% width. 
The CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 5%;
}
```

is making that element 110% wide. change the width to 90%;